# TYPO3 9 Install-Wizard pagesSlugs crashes on many pages installation

Tags: typo3-9.x

We are currently upgrading a TYPO3-Installation with about 60.000 Pages to V9.

The Upgrade-Wizard "Introduce URL parts ("slugs") to all existing pages" does not finish. In Browser (Install-Tool) I get a time-out.
Calling it via

```
./vendor/bin/typo3cms upgrade:wizard pagesSlugs
```

results in following Error:

```
[ Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessSignaledException ]  
The process has been signaled with signal "9".
```

After using my favourite internet-search-engine I thinks that means most likely "out of memory".

Sadly the database doesn't seams to be touched at all - so no pages got the slug after that. That means just running this process several times will not help. Observing the Process the PHP-Process takes all memory it can get, then filling the swap. When the swap is full the process crashes.
Tested so far on a local Docker with 16GB RAM Host and on a Server with 8 Cores but 8GB RAM (DB is on an external Machine).

Any ideas to fix that?

Comment: What is your PHP memory_limit setting? Have you tried calling it with `php -d memory_limit=-1 vendor/bin/typo3 upgrade:run pagesSlugs`? Do you use typo3cms (from typo3_console extension?) instead of the default entry point (vendor/bin/typo3) for a specific reason?

Comment: Well I use typo3-console because I got used to it. Shouldn't make any difference because for some commands its just a wrapper - right? Memory-Limit and execution-time are already very high. It points out that my problem is related to a messed up db-structure - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging I found out that the reason for this are messed up relations in database. So there are non deleted pages which points to non existing parents. This was mainly caused by a heavy clean up of the database before. Beside the wizard is not checking that and could be an improvement on it - the main problem is my database in that case.